# 403 Developer Inactive on an HTTP pull

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I am trying to query some XML from a hotel database using Ruby, and am getting the results:

## 403 Developer Inactive

I used the code:

```
require 'net/http'

url = URI.parse('URL of the HTTP query')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

I would give the actual URL, but it contains the API key/etc...so I really cannot divulge it.

Is there anything wrong with the code or might it be on the company needing to activate the key?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 is the HTTP status code `FORBIDDEN`, which leads me to believe you have a problem authenticating your API request, maybe because of a wrong key or something.